# Replace last nonblank line with a command output

Tags: shell-script, shell, macos

I have a `.env` file like

```
PARAM1=val
PARAM2=val
```

I want to replace the last noblank line with another file content

So far I have something like below:

```bash
{ (sed -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;ba' -e '}' local.env | sed '$d' local.env && printf "CONFIG=%s" "$(cat config.json | jq -c .)") >local.env.mod; } && mv local.env.mod local.env
```

Is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about *better* (the best would be to know that it's the line that sets `PARAM2` that needs replacing, but you specifically say "the last non-empty line"), but the `ed` editor is really good at applying editing procedures to text files that are too complicated for `sed` (but do note that it reads the full text into memory, unlike `sed`):

```bash
$ cat new-content
this is the new content
```

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' '?.? d' '-r new-content' ,p Q | ed -s file
PARAM1=val
this is the new content
```

The editing script that `ed` gets is

```
?.? d
-r new-content
,p
Q
```

This starts by searching backwards for the first line that contains anything (note that spaces count here, even though they are not visible; change the `.` to `[[:graph:]]` to only care about visible characters), and deletes it.

Deleting a line moves the cursor down to the line after, so the `-` in front of `r` tells `ed` to insert (read) the contents of `new-contens` on the line above where the cursor is.

The final `,p` and `Q` displays the full document on standard output, and then quits the editor unconditionally.   If you want to make an "in-line edit", change these two commands to the single `wq` command, which writes the modified document back to the file and quits.

To insert the contents of the `new-content` file after `=` in `CONFIG=`, replacing the end of the file, from the last non-blank line onwards:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' '?[[:graph:]]?,$ c' 'CONFIG=' . 'r new-content' '-,.j' ,p Q | ed -s file
PARAM1=val
CONFIG=this is the new content
```

The `c` command changes lines, and we use it to replace the lines from the last non-empty line to the end.  The input to the `c` command is ended with a single dot, and the content of `new-content` is inserted after with `r`.  The `j` command joins the previous line (`CONFIG=`) with the line we just inserted (we assume it's a single line, because it is in your question).

Answer (score 2):

You could reverse the file and replace the **first** non-blank line

```bash
printf -v new_line 'CONFIG=%s' "$(jq -c . config.json)"

tac local.env \
| awk -v line="$new_line" '
      !n && /[^[:blank:]]/ {print line; n = 1; next}
      {print}
  ' \
| tac > local.env.mod && mv local.env.mod local.env
```